# Can I retrieve the confidence of the transcription from Azure Cognitive Services?

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-services

I'm using this code to transcribe wav files using Azure Cognitive Services. Once the whole thing has been transcribed can I get a confidence score?

```
        private static async Task<string> TranscribeWav(SpeechConfig config, string fileName)
    {
        var taskCompleteionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

        var transcriptionStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        using (var audioInput = AudioConfig.FromWavFileInput(fileName))
        {
            using (var recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(config, audioInput))
            {
                // Subscribes to events.  
                recognizer.Recognizing += (sender, eventargs) =>
                {
                    //TODO: Handle recognized intermediate result  
                    //Console.WriteLine(eventargs.Result.Text);
                };

                recognizer.Recognized += (sender, eventargs) =>
                {
                    if (eventargs.Result.Reason == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech)
                    {
                        transcriptionStringBuilder.Append(eventargs.Result.Text);
                    }
                    else if (eventargs.Result.Reason == ResultReason.NoMatch)
                    {
                        //TODO: Handle not recognized value  
                    }
                };

                recognizer.Canceled += (sender, eventargs) =>
                {
                    if (eventargs.Reason == CancellationReason.Error)
                    {
                        //TODO: Handle error  
                    }

                    if (eventargs.Reason == CancellationReason.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"End of stream ({transcriptionStringBuilder.ToString()})...");
                    }

                    taskCompleteionSource.TrySetResult(0);
                };

                recognizer.SessionStarted += (sender, eventargs) =>
                {
                    //Started recognition session  
                };

                recognizer.SessionStopped += (sender, eventargs) =>
                {
                    //Ended recognition session  
                    taskCompleteionSource.TrySetResult(0);
                };

                // Starts continuous recognition. Uses StopContinuousRecognitionAsync() to stop recognition.  
                await recognizer.StartContinuousRecognitionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                // Waits for completion.  
                // Use Task.WaitAny to keep the task rooted.  
                Task.WaitAny(new[] { taskCompleteionSource.Task });

                // Stops recognition.  
                await recognizer.StopContinuousRecognitionAsync();
            }
        }

        return transcriptionStringBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

My intent is to submit a wav file to a cognitive service for transcription. I'm new to azure and would like to do this sequentially so also feel free to tell me my code is inefficient or wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, For getting the confidence Score you need to configure SpeechConfig as shown below for the detailed output format.
config.OutputFormat = OutputFormat.Detailed; 
Use the Result.Best() method that will return the best possible recognition's with the detailed output. The detailed output has the Confidence Score to show.

Please refer the following [Speech recognition samples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/samples/csharp/sharedcontent/console/speech_recognition_samples.cs#L172) that can help you.I hope this helps!

Comment: @Mike I have also a same question can you tell me [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73568223/can-i-retrieve-the-confidence-of-the-recognized-from-azure-cognitive-services1)