# Can I retrieve the confidence of the recognized from Azure Cognitive Services?

Tags: c#, winforms, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am making speech to text app in C sharp window form. it was working fine and running in visual studio but

I'm using this code to recognized  using Microsoft Azure Cognitive Services. Once the whole thing has been recognized  can I get a confidence score in c sharp window form?

How can I solve this?

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Audio;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private bool isRecognizing = false;
        private SpeechRecognizer recognizer;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void initRecognizer()
        {
            
            SpeechConfig config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("key", "region");
            if (Properties.Settings.Default.Punctuation)
            {
                config.SetServiceProperty("punctuation", "explicit", ServicePropertyChannel.UriQueryParameter);
            }
            //AudioConfig audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromMicrophoneInput();
            recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(config/*, audioConfig*/);
            recognizer.Recognized += SpeechRecognizer_Recognized;
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            initRecognizer();

        }

        private void SpeechRecognizer_Recognized(object sender, SpeechRecognitionEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech)
            {
                if (e.Result.Text.ToLower().Equals("new line") || e.Result.Text.ToLower().Equals("newline"))
                {
                    SendKeys.SendWait(Environment.NewLine);
                }
                else
                {
                    SendKeys.SendWait(e.Result.Text);
                }

            }
        }


        private void Startstop()
        {
            if (isRecognizing)
            {
                recognizer.StopContinuousRecognitionAsync();
                picture_btn.Image = Properties.Resources.green;
                startToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Start";
                pictureBox1.Enabled = true;                
                isRecognizing = false;
                timer1.Stop();
                timer1.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                picture_btn.Image = Properties.Resources.red;
                startToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Stop";
                pictureBox1.Enabled = false;
                recognizer.StartContinuousRecognitionAsync();
                isRecognizing = true;
                timer1.Interval = 600;
                timer1.Start();
                timer1.Enabled = true;

            }
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Startstop();
        }

        private void Form1_Move(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
            {
                ShowInTaskbar = true;
                notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
                this.Hide();
                notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(1000);
            }
        }

        private void Form1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            ShowInTaskbar = true;
            notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            notifyIcon1.Visible = false;

        }

        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }


        void SettingFormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            initRecognizer();
        }

        private void startToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Startstop();
        }



        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (picture_btn.Tag.Equals("red"))
            {
                picture_btn.Image = Properties.Resources.grey;
                picture_btn.Tag = "grey";
            }
            else
            {
                picture_btn.Image = Properties.Resources.red;
                picture_btn.Tag = "red";
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var myForm = new Form2();
            myForm.FormClosed += SettingFormClosed;
            myForm.Show();
        }

        private void notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Show();
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
            {
                notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
                this.Hide();
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You should always read through the documentation of a service before deep diving into it. The documentation will cover important configuration aspect and should detail limitations.

> **[Azure - Cognitive Services - Speech Service - Speech-to-text documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/index-speech-to-text)**
> This is the landing page for all the standard resources for the *speech-to-text* service, read through all these to understand how the service was designed to work and to gain code examples for common scenarios.
>
> - **[Get speech recognition results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-speech-recognition-results?pivots=programming-language-csharp)**
>   this is the guidance specific to the `SpeechRecognizer` events and `Results`
> - **[Recognized offset and duration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-speech-recognition-results?pivots=programming-language-csharp#recognized-offset-and-duration)**
>   This section explains how to get the detailed results.

### Step 1 - Config

You need to configure your `SpeechRecognizer` instance to return *Detailed* output:

```
SpeechConfig config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("key", "region");
// Detailed output will include confidence factor
config.OutputFormat = OutputFormat.Detailed;

if (Properties.Settings.Default.Punctuation)
{
    config.SetServiceProperty("punctuation", "explicit", ServicePropertyChannel.UriQueryParameter);
}
```

### Step 2 - Access *Details* from the `Best()` extension method

This is documented in this section: [Recognized offset and duration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-speech-recognition-results?pivots=programming-language-csharp#recognized-offset-and-duration) however the general idea is that we call the `e.Result.Best()` extension method to retrieve the details about the results.

> Make sure you have the following using statement to make the `Best()` method available:
>
> ```
>  using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech;
> ```

```
private void SpeechRecognizer_Recognized(object sender, SpeechRecognitionEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech)
    {
        if (e.Result.Text.ToLower().Equals("new line") || e.Result.Text.ToLower().Equals("newline"))
            SendKeys.SendWait(Environment.NewLine);
        else
            SendKeys.SendWait(e.Result.Text);

        // Get the detailed results
        var detailedResults = e.Result.Best();
        if (detailedResults != null && detailedResults.Any())
        {
            // The first item in detailedResults corresponds to the recognized text.
            // This is not necessarily the item with the highest confidence number.
            var bestResults = detailedResults?.ToList()[0];
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("\tConfidence: {0}\n\tText: {1}\n\tLexicalForm: {2}\n\tNormalizedForm: {3}\n\tMaskedNormalizedForm: {4}",
                bestResults.Confidence, 
                bestResults.Text, 
                bestResults.LexicalForm, 
                bestResults.NormalizedForm, 
                bestResults.MaskedNormalizedForm));  
    }
}
```

As an example, you can get this level of information back from the service, I have also enabled the `config.RequestWordLevelTimestamps()` to get word-level timestamps:

[image: example results from speech to text service]

Comment: speechConfig.RequestWordLevelTimestamps() for this we need to make custom speech model

Comment: `RequestWordLevelTimestamps()` doesn't need a custom model, its a metric of the processor, not the model.